# Setting up a kind of BelongsToThrough relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is my current situation:

- I have a Task model.
- Tasks have owners (a belongsTo relationship)
- Owners have accounts (yet another belongsTo relationship)

I'd like to set up a "belongsToThrough" relationship from Tasks to Accounts.

My first solution was to define a relationship in the Tasks model, like this:

```php
    public function account(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->owner->account();
    }
```

With it I could call `$task->account` and retrieve a task's account easily. The problem is that this doesn't work with `load`/`with`, which in turn causes problems because I can't `refresh()` a task that has had the account loaded in (because refresh uses load). The error just states `Trying to call account() on null` which was honestly expected.

My second solution was to change the relationship method to:

```php
    public function account(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->owner()->first()->account();
    }
```

With this, I can also simply call `$task->account` and retrieve the model, and when loading, it doesn't work (returns null), but also doesn't throw any errors. I don't need to load this relationship in, it just happens that sometimes I need to refresh models and having the load method throw an error is not ok.

**In summary**

What I'm looking for is kind of a BelongsToThrough, as a Task would BelongTo an Account through an Owner (User). Is there a way to do this that works using both `$task->account` and `$task->load('account')`. Before you tell me I can load it using `owner.account`, I know that, but `refresh()` will do it automatically with `load('account')` so I need it to work like that, not with the dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working with `load()`, you'll need to define an `account` relationship on the `owner` model, if you haven't done so already. Like this:

```
public function account() :BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AccountsTable);
}
```

Then use dot notation when calling `load()` on your task model like:

`$task->load('owner.account');`

Comment: That's already defined, and I know that the load works with the `owner.account` notation. The problem is that if I do `$task->account` and then sometime later do `$task->refresh()` it breaks if I'm using the first method, and just returns null when using the second one. The reason is that `account` becomes a task relationship, and refresh tries loading in `$task->load('account')`. My current solution works for my use case, I was just wondering if there was a way to define this that worked with `load('account')`

Comment: When you first retrieve the `$task` model, why can't you do `$task->load('account')`? Then you've got the account ready for when you need to use it later and it'll be reloaded when you `$task->refresh()`.

Comment: calling load isn't a problem, in fact I don't even use it. The "problem" is that refresh does, and when using the first method, the load simply throws an exception, because it doesn't work and when using the second method the load returns null. I don't really need the load to work in my current use case. But it would be good if it did, because it might be required in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using eager loading

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ParentModel', 'foreignkey', 'localkey');
}
```

After that you can easily fetch relation data with load/with.

Thanks,